# Correct Syntax for a complex CASE statement inside Cursor

Tags: sql, cursor, case, sql-update

I need help with the correct syntx for my CASE statement inside my Cursor.

Background: What I want this CASE statement to do is to look through the table Concatenated_File and in the column FileID, any row that says 'File1', I want it to update the MRNID in the appropriate table, which is titled Load_File_1.  And I want to continue the CASE statement that any row that says 'File2', I want it to update the MRNID in the appropriate table, Load_File_2.

This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @FILEID AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @MRNID AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @UniqueID AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @LNAME AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @FNAME AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Birthdate AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SSN AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_MRNID AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_UniqueID AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_LNAME AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_FNAME AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_Birthdate AS VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @HOLD_SSN AS VARCHAR(255)

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE curDB CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

-----------------------------------------------
SELECT UniqueID, MRNID, LNAME, FNAME, Birthdate, SSN
FROM Concatenated_File
ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME, Birthdate, SSN
-----------------------------------------------

-- initialize variables
select @FILEID=''
select @MRNID=''
select @UniqueID=''
select @FNAME=''
select @LNAME=''
select @Birthdate=''
select @SSN=''
select @HOLD_MRNID=''
select @HOLD_UniqueID=''
select @HOLD_FNAME=''
select @HOLD_LNAME=''
select @HOLD_Birthdate=''
select @HOLD_SSN=''

OPEN curDB

FETCH NEXT FROM curDB into @FILEID, @MRNID, @UniqueID, @FNAME, @LNAME, @Birthdate, @SSN
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN

        IF @LNAME = @HOLD_LNAME and @FNAME = @HOLD_FNAME and @Birthdate = @HOLD_Birthdate and @SSN = @HOLD_SSN
              BEGIN

                    select @FILEID
                        CASE
                            When @FILEID = 'File1' Then
                            Update Load_File1
                            Set MRNID = @HOLD_MRNID
                            Where UniqueID = @UniqueID

                            When @FILEID = 'File2' Then
                            Update Load_File2
                            Set MRNID = @HOLD_MRNID
                            Where UniqueID = @UniqueID



              END
        ELSE

              BEGIN
                    select @HOLD_UniqueID = @UniqueID
                    select @HOLD_MRNID = @MRNID
                    select @HOLD_FNAME = @FNAME
                    select @HOLD_LNAME = @LNAME
                    select @HOLD_Birthdate = @Birthdate
                    select @HOLD_SSN = @SSN
              END
        FETCH NEXT FROM curDB into @FILEID, @MRNID, @UniqueID, @FNAME, @LNAME, @Birthdate, @SSN
  END
```

CLOSE curDB
DEALLOCATE curDB

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is not a flow of control construct you need `IF`

```
IF @FILEID = 'File1'
    UPDATE Load_File1
    SET MRNID = @HOLD_MRNID
    WHERE UniqueID = @UniqueID
ELSE IF @FILEID = 'File2'
    UPDATE Load_File2
    SET MRNID = @HOLD_MRNID
    WHERE UniqueID = @UniqueID
```

I'm not sure exactly what your cursor update logic is doing. Generally you are better off using set based techniques though.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an idea that I needed an IF...ELSE statement, but I wasn't sure. It worked great. Thanks again!